# How to get sum of all running jobs from start time to end time?

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-pinot

I have this table with millions of records:

[image]

I want to get the sum of all running jobs from `Start Time` to `End Time`. For example query 1:
Between 1:00 and 4:00 how many jobs were running?
Then here the answer will be 3 (Job1, Job2 & Job7).

I can use joins but want the approach that takes least time for millions of records.

Comment: Why you think it needs join? It looks to be a simple where clause (```where start_time between x and y AND end_time between x and y```). Please post sample query from your end, to make it more clear.

Comment: The WHERE condition can be simplified to `start_time > x AND end_time < y`. But if the author wants not just jobs that are sitting entirely inside the given interval but also all jobs that start OR finish during the given time interval - he will need to use an OVERLAP function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a `subquery` that gets your *job* `COUNT` between your *start* and *end* times along with a `GROUP_CONCAT` to group all of your *jobs* in a single, comma delimited row:

```
SELECT jobs AS "Jobs", job_count AS "Job Count"
FROM
(
SELECT
  1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ', ') as jobs,
  COUNT(job) AS job_count
FROM
  sample_table 
WHERE
  start_time >= '1:00'
  AND
  end_time <= '4:00'
GROUP BY
  1
) a
```

**Result:**

| Jobs | Job Count |
| --- | --- |
| Job1, Job2, Job7 | 3 |

Alternatively, you can use a `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT
  1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ', ') as jobs,
  COUNT(job) AS job_count
FROM
  sample_table 
WHERE
  start_time >= '1:00'
  AND
  end_time <= '4:00'
GROUP BY
  1
) SELECT jobs AS "Jobs", job_count AS "Job Count" FROM cte
```

**Result:**

| Jobs | Job Count |
| --- | --- |
| Job1, Job2, Job7 | 3 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gApsEiGq).

**Notes:**

- I used a dummy value of `1` for the grouping which is why I used a `subquery` and `CTE`, if you don't mind outputting the column you can remove the `subquery` or `CTE`.
- You can add a `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` attributes to the `GROUP_CONCAT` but this will likely impact your performance.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT job ORDER BY job ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
```

- Since you're dealing with a large dataset, I would ensure your table is properly `indexed`. I'm not sure    what your key columns are but setting up `indexes` will speed up the query. See [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).